# Move window to corner of screen using NSIS

Tags: windows, winapi, positioning, nsis

I am trying to reposition a nsDialogs window using the following code:
http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Moving_install_window_to_a_corner_of_the_screen

I am not including the System.nsh file as if I include I get the error:

```
!define: "IMAGE_BITMAP" already defined!
!include: error in script: "C:\Program Files (x86)\NSIS\Examples\System\System.nsh" on line 267
```

If I do not include the System.nsh file then I get the following error:

```
unknown variable/constant "{stRECT}" detected,
```

What is the stRect variable? How to avoid at least one of these errors and reposition my window using NSIS? I am using the latest version of NSIS.

Comment: It is not a variable, it is just !define stRECT "(i, i, i, i) i" and that is just a helper define to simplify the system::call syntax.

Comment: got it just looked in System.nsh! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
!include nsDialogs.nsh
!undef IMAGE_BITMAP
!include "${NSISDIR}\Examples\System\System.nsh"
```

...if nsDialogs.nsh is the conflicting header you probably have to !undef the other image types as well.

Comment: Found a fix ... Create a local copy of System.nsh and remove all the defines I don't need. Better than so many undefs.

Comment: This is clearly a bug, I'll fix it for the next version so modifying your local copy is fine (The script is no longer compatible with 2.46 though, if you need that, !undef is better). Another solution is to just search&replace ${stRect} with the actual value and then don't include System.nsh at all...